# How do i make two QGraphicsViews scroll simultaneously?

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, qgraphicsview

Let's say i have two QGraphicsViews:

```
QGraphicsView *view1;
QGraphicsView *view2;
```

where `view1` is big view that has vertical scroll bar(this view is guaranteed to contain an image that is bigger than viewport) and is to contain some drawing, put by user, and `view2` is ruler-like view that represents *y* value of the according part of `view1`. What i want is to simultaneously scroll `view2`, once `view1` is scrolled. I also don't want `view1` to have any scroll bars. Is that possible? If so - how? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would create a container widget which captures all scroll events and then implement scrolling for both QGraphicsViews. For scrollbar, you can retrieve a pointer to it from GraphicsView and use QWidget::hide() function.

Comment: If the first one only contains the image and the scond one only a ruler, you should consider to use one `QGraphicsView`

Comment: @RomhaKorev well, not exactly. Second one only contains a ruler, and first one contains the image, but user also draws on the first one. I should have mentioned it in the question. Should i still use only one QGraphicsView?

Comment: From what I understood, you should use only one `QGraphicsView`. If you provide a minimal and complete example, I will be able to give an answer. But, first, check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588152/how-to-make-a-ruler-on-the-border-of-a-qgraphicsview/56606196#56606196) fits your needs.

Comment: @RomhaKorev it seems to fit my needs, thank you.