# How can I have a frozen horizontal header in a scrollable QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a single-column QTableWidget for my application (`_tw`). I want this QTableWidget to be scrollable, both vertically and horizontally. I hid the vertical header but I need the horizontal header.
The problem is that I can't get a "frozen" (insensible to horizontal scroll) horizontal header, and the text of this header is often hidden in the scroll. Furthermore, after the vertical scroll bar, I can see pixels of my horizontal header, which is unwanted.

I have tried to tackle the issue differently, as I already struggled to make this table scrollable horizontally. Unsucessfully, I tried to repositionate the header each time the scroll bar is moved. Even if I failed, this feels more like a workaround than a solution.

```cpp
_tw->setHorizontalScroolBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
_tw->setHorizontalScroolMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
_tw->verticalHeader()->hide();
_tw->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Fixed);
_tw->horizontalHeader()->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
_tw->horizontalHeader()->setFixedHeight(_headerHeight);
_tw->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

_tw->horizontalHeader()->setFixedWitdh(_tableWidth);
_tw->setFixedWidth(_tableWidth);

_tw->setColumnWidth(0, _tableWidth + _offset);
```

I expect the horizontal header to be at the same width of the table, and insensible to scroll. It is currently not the case: the header has the size of the column (bigger than what is displayed on the screen). Since the headter text is aligned horizontally, it is not shown and moves with the scroll.

Comment: The most simple solution that comes to my mind would be a `QAbstractProxyModel` connected to a custom slider, which would only show the desired rows.

Comment: Or, you can simply create a `QHeaderView`, but that won't scroll horizontally with the rest of the QTableWidget.

Comment: @MartinHennings you gave me an even simpler idea: I created a `QPushButton` and gave it the look of a `QHeaderView`. Since my layout were simples, I just had to hide the horizontal header, and gave the new button the desired header witdh and height.
There is a 1px gap between the button and the table in spite of my efforts, but it's minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the others solutions I tried gave me some pixel gaps that I found too noticeable. I decided to go big, and create a custom `QWidget` specifically for answering this problem.

Basically I just created a `QWidget` simply containing the `QTableWidget`, with no header. For the sake of keeping everything at the same size, I aded a line, which is going to stay empty and will be hidden by a `QPushButton`. I give this line the height I want for my header, for the same reason.

After modifying the behaviour of the `QTableWidget` so it would skip the first line, I created a `QPushButton` with my custom widget as the parent. Fortunately enough in my application, they have the same look as the other `QHeader`. To make the button "on top of" the empty line, since this is a custom widget, a simple `button->move(0, 2);` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a custom class that will apply header-like area to any `QAbstractScrollArea` (including `QTableWidget`) and setting viewport margins on your tablewidget. You won't need to mangle with header not beeing scrolled, but if you need some header-like behaviour, you will need to do it manually.

Untested code:

```
class Header: public QWidget
{
public:
    Header(QAbstractScrollArea* parent=nullptr): QWidget(parent)
    {
        setFixedSize(parent->width(), 40);
    }

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
    {
        QPainter painter(this);
        QFont font("Arial");
        QFontMetrics fm(font);
        QRect txtRect;
        QString txt = "Header_name";
        txtRect = fm.boundingRect(txt).trabslated(dx, dy);//translate it to position you want
        painter.setFont(font);
        painter.painter.drawText(txtRect, txt);
    }
};
```

Then set viewport margins on your tablewidget, something like this:

```
_tw->setViewportMargins(0, 40, 0, 0);
```

Then just create instance of `Header`:

```
Header *header = new Header(_tw);
```

If this code works - [Romha Korev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110683/romha-korev) gets the credit. I took the idea from his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588152/how-to-make-a-ruler-on-the-border-of-a-qgraphicsview/56606196#56606196).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is strange, but the line "setViewportMargins" returns an error in my project. Otherwise, it seems like an elegant answer !